# FTDI COM port not showing correctly on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, python, serial-port, ftdi

I am using python and I have trouble connecting to a device through an FTDI Serial-USB connection.

On a Windows 7 laptop, it works correctly and does not give any issue, ports are seen as they should and the connection goes straight without any trouble.

On another laptop, with Windows 10, it is all another story. Sometimes the python script is not able to see any device connected. From the Device Manager I can correctly see the COM port attached but if I use the `mode` command from the prompt it does not report any port, or it gives the same device on another COM.

The python code is exactly the same on both laptops.

I checked and I am using the latest driver from FTDI and I have never seen any issue regarding fake FTDI chip, even if I could not assure it is original. Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

As I dont have 50 rep yet, I cannot add it as a comment:

Are you sure that you use the VCP driver and not the D2XXX? What type of FTDI do you use and have you tried to read out the device via the FT_PROG tool provided by the manufacturer?

You can try to remove the current driver with the CDM_Unistaller to make a clean installation of the VCP driver. Sometimes it helps.

Maybe you find this handy as well: `python -m serial.tools.list_ports -v` excuted via the console should list all available ports. One can use `serial.tools.list_ports` as well within a script:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

print(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
```

Comment: I will try these suggestions and will comment on the results whenever I have the chance. Thank you.